# $T,S: V\to V$, prove that $TS$ and $ST$ have the same eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

hey I was trying to prove this proposition by dividing to cases and this is what I've got so far:
let's assume without loss of generality that T is invertible:
ST = [T][S]
TS = [S][T]

```
Pst(x) = |[T][S]-גI| = |[T][S]-גI|*|[T][T^-1]| = |[T^-1]|*|[T][S]-גI|*|[T]| =
|[S]-[T^-1]גI|*|[T]| = |[S]-ג[T^-1]|*|[T]| = |[S][T]-גI| = Pts(x)
```

they have the same characteristic polynomial, thus the same eigenvalues.
but what about the case when both are non-invertible?

would appreciate any kind of help.

Comment: http://people.math.sc.edu/howard/Classes/700/charAB.pdf

Answer (score 2):

You did half the work (and you're right) : if $T$ or $S$ in an element of $\mathrm{GL}_{n}(\mathbb{C})$ (*i.e.* an invertible matrix), the following equality holds : $\mathrm{P}_{TS}=\mathrm{P}_{ST}$. Here, $\mathrm{P}_{TS}$ (resp. $\mathrm{P}_{ST}$) denotes the characteristic polynomial of $TS$ (resp. $ST$).

If $T$ (or $S$) is no invertible, you can use the density of $\mathcal{GL}_{n}(\mathbb{C})$ into $\mathcal{M}_{n}(\mathbb{C})$. In other words : there exist a sequence $(T_{n})_{n \geq 0}$ of invertible matrices such that $T_{n} \mathop{\longrightarrow} \limits_{n \to +\infty} T$.

For all $n$, the following holds :

$$ \mathrm{P}_{T_{n}S} = \mathrm{P}_{ST_{n}}. $$

By continuity of the characteristic polynomial,

$$ \mathrm{P}_{T_{n}S} \, \mathop{\longrightarrow} \limits_{n \to +\infty} \, \mathrm{P}_{TS} $$

and, as well,

$$ \mathrm{P}_{ST_{n}} \, \mathop{\longrightarrow} \limits_{n \to +\infty} \, \mathrm{P}_{ST}. $$

As a consequence : $\mathrm{P}_{TS} = \mathrm{P}_{ST}$.

Answer (score 2):

Considering nonzero eigenvalues first, suppose $ST$ has a nonzero eigenvalue $\lambda$, so that there's some nonzero $v$ such that $$STv = \lambda v.$$

What can we say about $TS$? Since $S(Tv) = \lambda v$, let's see what happens when we apply $TS$ to $Tv$:

\begin{align*}TS(Tv) 
&= T(\lambda v)\\
&= \lambda Tv \end{align*}

where the latter holds because $T$ is linear. Note that by our assumptions, we know $Tv \neq 0$, as $S(Tv) = \lambda v \neq 0$.

Thus, if $\lambda$ is a nonzero eigenvalue of $ST$, it must be an eigenvalue of $TS$. A very similar argument will show that eigenvalues of $TS$ are also eigenvalues of $ST$.

Finally, $0$ is an eigenvalue of $TS \iff$ at least one of $S$ or $T$ is singular $\iff 0$ is an eigenvalue of $ST$.

Comment: You should mention that $v$ is nonzero. But you don't know that $Tv$ is nonzero unless $T$ is invertible. Handling the case of singular $ST$ can be done as in other answers (limiting argument). Another possibility is adding some multiple of identity, that will shift all eigenvalues by that multiple. Since there are only finite number of eigenvalues but uncountable number of possible multiples it is possible to make ST nonsingular by a shift.

Comment: @dioid Noted, thank you. I've made the argument more precise. Perhaps it should be noted that since the OP seemed to mention characteristic polynomials in passing, I assumed the goal was merely to show that $ST$ and $TS$ have the same *set* of eigenvalues, not characteristic polynomial.

Answer (score 1):

Though Jibounet's answer covers what is needed, let me add something from a general group-theoretic viewpoint: In any group $G$ if $x,y\in G$ are two elements then the elements $xy$ and $yx$ are conjugate (could be the same), because $  y(xy)y^{-1}= yx$.

Now apply this to group of non-singular matrices, then $ST$ and $TS$ are conjugate: and in matrices instead of using the word conjugate it is customary to say these transformations are *similar*.

Similar matrices have the same characteristic polynomials and hence the same eigen values. This is straight from the definition: $$\det(ABA^{-1}-\lambda I)= \det\big( A(B-\lambda I)A^{-1}\big)=\det A \det (B-\lambda I)\det A^{-1}= \det (B-\lambda I).t$$ Of course for singular $S,T$ one has to use the limiting argument of Jibounet.